# Utilizando Open Iconic

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, estoy intentando usar los iconos de Open Iconic.
Me recomiendan descargar una carpeta llamada open-iconic-master, la cual ya la tengo, pero no tengo ni idea sobre donde la instalo.
¿Alguien me explica donde deberia colocar esa carpeta dentro de mi proyecto para que pueda usar dichos iconos?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo arregle.
He usado esto:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-m/h/cUDAhf6/iBRixTbuc8+Rg2cIETQtPcH9D3p2Kg0=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/open-iconic/1.1.1/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-BJ/G+e+y7bQdrYkS2RBTyNfBHpA9IuGaPmf9htub5MQ=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Aunque, ¿Alguien conoce algo mejor?
Los tutoriales sobre como usar Open Icon son confusos y esto fue lo unico que encontre que funcionaba.